# Http proxy over cloudflare tunnel with public hostname

Tags: cloudflare, tunnel, warp

I am trying to run HTTP or https proxy over Cloudflare tunnel with a public hostname but wasn't successful.

Theoretically, it should be possible as Cloudflare tunnel only allows HTTP traffic accessible to the public, but it doesn't work.

It is working fine with warp client and private IP. Also it can see the squid http error page on port 443 but doesn't work as a proxy on the same port.

Am I missing something, or is it possible at all?

Comment: It is possible to run a http proxy as a CF tunnel Origin, but you're not providing enough information to help you find the right config.

Comment: What I want is actually this: VPS with CF tunnel and squid proxy server --> public hostname like prox.x.com:443 
so this can work like the public can add  prox.x.com:443 as an HTTP proxy and connect
is it possible?
The point is that censorship cant see the VPS because the traffic goes through CF

Comment: Perfectly doable with HAProxy, I don't see why you'd have a problem with Squid.